# Macro for re-occuring string replacement

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want a macro that I can use like this:

```
CREATE_URL(@"{SOME-TOKEN}/some/url/path");
```

The macro should then replace my token analogue to the following call:

```
NSString *initialURL = @"{SOME-TOKEN}/some/url/path";
[initialURL stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"{SOME-TOKEN}" withString:@"http://server.com"]
```

So I have defined my macro like this, which does not work unfortunately:

```
#define CREATE_URL(url) [##url stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"{SOME-TOKEN}" withString:@"http://server.com"];
```

I the two errors when using the macro:

```
Missing '[' at start of message send expression
Pasting formed '[@', an invalid preprocessing token
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this?

```
#define CREATE_URL(url) [url stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"{SOME-TOKEN}" withString:@"http://server.com"]
```

It should work fine... why the ## and the ;?

Comment: It is used to expand a macro. For example, if you need a variable name generated at compile time with the Macro http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fnumnum.htm